# Uniform convergence of the sequences $\{f_n\}$ in $C([a,b])$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, compactness, uniform-convergence

> If I have an uniformly convergent sequence $\{f_n\}$ in the space of
>   continuous functions $C([a,b])$ and $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to
>   $f$, then how can I prove that $f \in C([a,b])$?

The uniformly convergent sequence $\{f_n\}$ has to have a limit in $C([a,b])$, otherwise it wouldn't even be convergent. $[a,b]$ is obviously bounded interval. The only thing that came to my mind is to show that $|f_n - f| \lt \epsilon  $.

Comment: "The uniformly convergent sequence$(f_n)_n$ has to have a limit in $C([a,b])$" -> what you write there is exactly what you are asked to prove, isn't it? I.e., that the limit *is* in $C([a,b])$.

Comment: Yes, but is it all?

Comment: Well, you state it is obvious, but it is not. You have to **show** $f$ belongs to $C[a,b]$, i.e. that it is continuous. (Things from a space $X$ can, sometimes, converge out of $X$ -- for instance, sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$ are known to sometimes converge to irrational numbers.)

Comment: Well, because $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly, then for $n \to \infty$ is the distance between them zero so generally $d(f_n,f) \lt \epsilon$ and $f \in [a,b]$.

Comment: That's not a proof... you want to show that $f$ is continuous: you have to do it. Here, you are simply stating the assumptions, and then writing the conclusion -- it's not a proof.

Comment: For instance, I could write exactly the same thing as you just wrote with "pointwise" instead of "uniformly" -- it would look almost the same, but the conclusion would be false.

Comment: I don't know how to write that proof. :(

Comment: Take $\varepsilon>0$ arbitrary, and $x_0\in [a,b]$ arbitrary. Find a $\delta$ such that for any $x\in[a,b]$ such that $\lvert x-x_0\rvert\leq \delta$, $\lvert f(x)-f(x_0) \rvert \leq \varepsilon$. You can use Salahamam_ Fatima's hint for that.

Comment: Ok I will try it, thank you.

Comment: So I want to show that $|fn - f|_{\infty}$ $\to 0$. Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ then exists $n_0 \in \Bbb N : m,n \ge n_0: max_{x \in [a,b]} |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| \lt \epsilon$.  So $f_n(x) - \epsilon \le f_m(x) \le f_n(x) + \epsilon$. If $m \to \infty$ we have $f_n(x) - \epsilon \le f(x) \le f_n(x) + \epsilon$. So $|fn(x) - f(x)| \le \epsilon$. For all $x \in [a,b]$ and for all $n \gt n_0: ||f_n-f|| \lt \epsilon$

Comment: No: you *know* that $\lVert f_n-f\rVert_\infty\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$. This is by assumption, as this is the definition of uniform convergence of $(f_n)_n$ to $f$. What you want to show is that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I see. Ok......

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

Let $c\in [a,b] $, then for $x\in [a,b] $ and $n\ge 0$,

$$|f (x)-f (c)|\le |f (x)-f_n (x)|+|f_n (x)-f_n (c)|+|f_n (c)-f (c)|$$

Comment: Which is less then 3 $\epsilon$, so $f(c) \in [a,b]$? I have seen something like this in arzela ascoli theorem but I miss the intuition for this.

Comment: Fix $\varepsilon>0$ arbitrary. You have to pick the "right" $n$ there (it depends on $\varepsilon$). Since you have uniform convergence, $$\lVert f-f_n\rVert_\infty \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$$ and so there exists $N_\varepsilon\geq 0$ such that for all $n\geq N_\varepsilon$, $\lVert f-f_n\rVert_\infty\leq \varepsilon$. Stick with that $N_\varepsilon$. Then, by definition, $\lvert f_{N_\varepsilon}(x) - f(x)\rvert_\leq \varepsilon$ and $\lvert f_{N_\varepsilon}(c) - f(c)\rvert_\leq \varepsilon$ (for any $x\in[a,b]$).

Comment: That takes care of two of the 3 terms. For the last, remember that $f_{N_\varepsilon}$ is continuous... (These two comments are only to help you with the hint. +1 for the answer, by the way.)

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks Clement. You are really a good man.

Comment: Speaking of Arzela-Ascoli, the functions from the sequence $\{\,f_n(x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ form an equicontinuous family on $[a,b]$.